# Union as sub query using MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to optimize a query using a union as a sub query.

Im not really sure how to construct the query though.

I'm using MYSQL 8.0.12

Here is the original query:

[image]

```
---------------
| c1     | c2 |
---------------
| 18182  | 0  |
| 18015  | 0  |
---------------
2 rows in set (0.35 sec)
```

**I'm sorry but the question doesn't stored if I paste the sql query as text and format using `ctrl+k`**

Output expected

```
---------------
| c1    | c2  |
---------------
| 18182 | 167 |
| 18015 | 0   |
---------------
```

As a output I would like to have the difference of rows between the two tables in `UNION ALL`.

I processed this question using the wizard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: I don't think you understand what your subquery is doing. Aside from that, do you **only** want the difference between the size of both tables?

Comment: @JettoMartínez Yes Sir, thanks for reply, I need the difference between the size of both tables...

Comment: Your example code doesn't give that result.  Your example code  won't even run; https://dbfiddle.uk/KjQZ0RLO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to go for this, including `UNION`, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it is IMO a bit 'hacky'. Instead, I suggest you use subqueries or use `CTE`s.

With subqueries

```sql
SELECT
    ABS(c_tbl_aaa.size - c_tbl_bbb.size) as diff
FROM (
        SELECT
           COUNT(*) as size
        FROM tbl_aaa
    ) c_tbl_aaa
CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
           COUNT(*) as size
        FROM tbl_bbb
    ) c_tbl_bbb
```

With `CTE`s, also known as `WITH`s

```sql
WITH c_tbl_aaa AS (
    SELECT
       COUNT(*) as size
    FROM tbl_aaa
), c_tbl_bbb AS (
    SELECT
       COUNT(*) as size
    FROM tbl_bbb
) 
SELECT
    ABS(c_tbl_aaa.size - c_tbl_bbb.size) as diff
FROM c_tbl_aaa
    CROSS JOIN c_tbl_bbb
```

In a practical sense, they are the same. Depending on the needs, you might want to define and join the results though, and in said cases, you could use a single number as a "pseudo id" in the select statement.

Since you only want to know the differences, I used the `ABS` function, which returns the absolute value of a number.

Let me know if you want a solution with `UNION`s anyway.

**Edit**: As @Rick James pointed out, `COUNT(*)` should be used in the subqueries to count the number of rows, as `COUNT(id_***)` will only count the rows with non-null values in that field.

Comment: I'll upvote if you change `,` to `CROSS JOIN`; teaching people old style syntax is a very bad idea.

Comment: `COUNT(id_aaa)` counts how many rows have `id_aaa IS NOT NULL`.  `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows.

Comment: @RickJames I left `id_***` as in the question as I don't know whether or not that field is nullable or if only those with a not null `id_***` matter, but yes, the question seems to imply that `COUNT(*)` is what's needed.

Answer (score 4):

Since a parenthesized `SELECT` can be used almost anywhere a expression can go:

```
SELECT
    ABS( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_aaa) -
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_bbb) ) AS diff;
```

Also, MySQL is happy to allow a `SELECT` without a `FROM`.